# How to get jQuery maphilight to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, maphilight

I cant get Mapilight http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/ to work!

These are my script links in the head of my html.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.maphilight.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.map').maphilight()
   
</script>
```

$('.map').maphilight()

here is my img and map

```html
<img class="map" title="Knight Campus, Warwick - Third Floor" src="/about/floorplans/knight/images/3rd_flr_2013_layout2.png" alt="Knight Campus, Warwick - Third Floor" usemap="#simple" />

<map name="simple">
  <area href="#" data-state="VT" data-full="Vermont" shape="rect" coords="377,34,407,43" />
  <area href="#" data-state="MA" data-full="Massachusetts" shape="rect" coords="358,47,406,56">
  <area shape="poly" coords="211,3,121,67,112,53,95,103,146,108,136,92,229,25" href="#" alt="arrow">
  <area shape="poly" coords="78,83,70,100,52,104,64,115,61,133,78,124,94,133,91,116,104,102,87,101,79,88" href="#" alt="star">
  <area shape="poly" coords="248,126,222,150,202,122,233,105,239,118,249,125,250,128" href="#" alt="a square">
  <area shape="poly" coords="151,249,175,225,182,222,167,193,136,221,153,250" href="#" alt="another square">
  <area shape="rect" coords="250,250,290,290" href="#" alt="Shadow for some">
</map>
```

PLEASE HELP!

Thanks

Comment: The areas will not highlight. When I inspect the code from the demos I see canvas tags... I tried putting those in but it did not work.

Comment: I'm also using boot strap so maybe thats throwing it off

Comment: You should add all that to the question. It's incomplete without that information.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your call to `maphilight()` in `document.ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.map').maphilight();
});
```

The following works perfectly for me:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/jquery.maphilight.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.map').maphilight({ alwaysOn: true });
            // uncomment this line for normal hover highlighting
            //$('.map').maphilight();
        });   
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="map" title="Knight Campus, Warwick - Third Floor" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/Big_Sur_June_2008.jpg/1024px-Big_Sur_June_2008.jpg" alt="Knight Campus, Warwick - Third Floor" usemap="#simple" />
    <map name="simple">
      <area href="#" data-state="VT" data-full="Vermont" shape="rect" coords="377,34,407,43" />
      <area href="#" data-state="MA" data-full="Massachusetts" shape="rect" coords="358,47,406,56">
      <area shape="poly" coords="211,3,121,67,112,53,95,103,146,108,136,92,229,25" href="#" alt="arrow">
      <area shape="poly" coords="78,83,70,100,52,104,64,115,61,133,78,124,94,133,91,116,104,102,87,101,79,88" href="#" alt="star">
      <area shape="poly" coords="248,126,222,150,202,122,233,105,239,118,249,125,250,128" href="#" alt="a square">
      <area shape="poly" coords="151,249,175,225,182,222,167,193,136,221,153,250" href="#" alt="another square">
      <area shape="rect" coords="250,250,290,290" href="#" alt="Shadow for some">
    </map>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @dbaker6 Take a look at the complete example I added.